# EF6 dynamically instantiate DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

Using Entity Framework 6 in Code-First, i'm working on a set of web applications to be used by a group of companies. Each company will have one database and their own DBContext to connect to it with.

The number of contexts and their names is only known by a config database which lists every company and the name of the DBContext that can access their data. I am trying to instantiate each of these contexts from some information stored in the config database. I was attempting to do this with a string context name but this requires some use of System.Activator.CreateInstance which is raising some concerns and complications. Is there a better method to achieve this task?

Comment: What are the concerns and complications you're experiencing? Also could you provide some example code from your `DBContext` and perhaps what you've already attempted with `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: Could you not do this with different connection strings? So connCompanyA, connCompanyB? So use a single DBContext class but pass the connection string via the constructor.

Comment: If I try to pass a connection string via the DbContext constructor, wouldn't that mean it would not resolve to a connection string at design time and such be unable to add migrations and update each database without using automatic migrations? From what i'd seen, auto migrations had no place in a production environment.

Comment: Migrations can be turned off and there are also explicit migrations.

Comment: @defect833 you should avoid auto migrations in production but if you need you can specify to migrate the database that triggered the migration request instead of default database. `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext,MyMigrationConfiguration>(true));` (true means use supplied context, )